# What is the java naming convention for use case class in clean architecture?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, clean-architecture

Naming convention for java class is using noun and not using verbs

But in clean architecture use case class contains verbs.

Could we use verbs in java class name in service layer/business layer?

Comment: Could you add the source that says about using verbs in use case classes? I'm not saying that it's wrong, but for situations like `ProvidingUserImage` you can use a name of `UserImageProvider`.

Comment: https://medium.com/slalom-engineering/clean-architecture-with-java-11-f78bba431041

Comment: It seems more understandable for me to use verb in service or use case java class name like SearchCustomerService or SearchCustomerUseCase for example

Comment: the postfix 'UseCase' seems redundant, but that's not the point. The 'search' word can also be noun in some cases. Taking the sample from the source `FindUser` can be transformed to `UserFinder`. But in the end, while the project grows and grows, we want it to be maintanable and quickly understendable so the point is to maintain same naming convention for all of the business requirements/use cases.

Comment: another example: https://medium.com/@mr.anmolsehgal/clean-architecture-fef10b093ad0

Comment: Same domain :) but I don't think that makes a difference so far you keep the same naming convention through whole project. The clean architecture is more about the separating the concerns (Create, Find, Login) and when having more entities separating all the needed Classes in proper packages. I.E. having all of the exceptions Classes defined in `...domain.exception` would make this package huge in future. I'd rather go with `user.exception`, `user.port`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Naming](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) in **Google Java Style Guide** is a good guideline for your reference.

Quoted from [Class names](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.2-class-names) section:

> Class names are written in UpperCamelCase.
>
> Class names are typically **nouns** or **noun phrases**. For example, Character or ImmutableList. Interface names may also be nouns or noun phrases (for example, List), but may sometimes be adjectives or adjective phrases instead (for example, Readable).

And verbs or verb phrases are usually used for **Method names**.

> Method names are written in lowerCamelCase.
>
> Method names are typically **verbs** or **verb phrases**. For example, sendMessage or stop.

Comment: isn't it just a `Java Style Guide`, isn't it? I could bet that Oracle (and probably earlier Sun) had the same naming convention in their docs.

Comment: It's more fundamental than a style guide. Java is an object-oriented programming language.  An object is a 'thing', not an action.  In Java, objects are defined by classes. Therefore, as a generalization (not an invariable rule), classes should have noun or noun phrase as a name.

Comment: @itwasntme Yes, Oracle does has this doc - [Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). But why I recommend Google is that it is much clear with example, not just naming convention.

Comment: @another-dave I think a use case is more a action than a thing

Comment: @LHCHIN kk, just curious :)
@another-dave pls take a look on the sources provided by OP, taking those under consideration, I think, it makes no difference if we use `UserFinder` instead of `FindUser` as long as we keep the same convention in whole project.
@chupee120 still a convention, earlier the names like `SearchUserService` `LoginUserService` were mostly used.

I think the convention and maintaining it in project is the key.

Comment: another example : AddProductToCartUseCase from https://crosp.net/blog/software-architecture/clean-architecture-part-2-the-clean-architecture/

Comment: Just to add lots of projects are having packages like `model`, `entity`, `service` with dozens of different classes doing completely different operations for different domain models. I'd rather go with package `user` having underlying packages of `service`, `model`, etc.

Comment: @chupee120 okz, the names contains some verbs but in the end those words describe in some details the noun. `UseCase`, `InputPort`, `OutputPort`.
But here I question myself and got no answer what would be better `BarkingDog` or `DogThatBarks`?

Comment: @chupee120 The URL you posted is to demonstrate the **concept** of *Clean Architecture* but I don't think its naming convention is good.